# 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndPlay

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have this AS3 script that worked so far...

```
stop();

b1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Info001);
function Info001(event:MouseEvent):void {
gotoAndPlay(2);
}

X.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Exit001);
function Exit001(e:MouseEvent) {
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
}
```

then, I added a class in the .fla file...

```
package
{
    import flash.system.System;
    import flash.system.Capabilities;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
    import flash.utils.setTimeout;
    import com.hdi.nativeExtensions.NativeAds;
    import com.hdi.nativeExtensions.NativeAdsEvent; 

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {       
        public var na : NativeApplication;
        private var admobId:String = 'a1514b5ef85e336';


        public function Main()      
        {
            na = NativeApplication.nativeApplication;
            na.addEventListener('exiting',exit,false,0,true);
            na.addEventListener('deactivate',exit,false,0,true);

            if ( stage ){
                stage.scaleMode = 'noScale';
                stage.align = 'TL';
            }           

            if ( loaderInfo ){
                loaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.INIT, init, false, 0, true );
            } else {
                init(null);
            }
        }
```

(the class is not complete here...)

and the buttons stopped working... :-/

I tried adding

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
```

but that's not enough... how can you make it work?

Comment: Is there an error, or does it just do nothing?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what's going on. What does the class do? I'm assuming from the name `Main` it's supposed to be a document class, but do you still have the code on the timeline or what? Also as Jeff said, is it giving the error you stated in the question title?

Comment: the class is for admob... the error is the title of the subject... would it help if i posted the whole class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to run `gotoAndPlay` in `Main`, it will throw that error because `Sprite`s don't have a timeline. If so, try extending `MovieClip` instead.

Comment: well.. i'm new to this whole class thing.. i'm used in having the as3 in the timeline... so, is there a way to have a timeline with the codes and a class? i know not more of these things :-/

Comment: I'm assuming you've set `Main` as your Document Class? By writing `Main extends Sprite`, you're telling Flash that your swf is based on a `Sprite`, and strictly `Sprites` don't have a `gotoAndPlay` method. Just try extending `MovieClip` instead?

Comment: umm... would you mind telling me how to extend that? it seems it's a bit our of my league :-/

Comment: At the top of your `Main` class, you have `public class Main extends Sprite`. Add `import flash.display.MovieClip` and write `public class Main extends MovieClip` instead. Have you tried reading up on classes a bit? There's [a page about inheritance here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcd.html)

Comment: It worked! THANK YOU! I'll have to read about class files if i am to get anywhere... THANK YOU! again!

Comment: Great! Hopefully that article is clear, but if you [look here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) you can see what `MovieClip` inherits from, and where it adds the `gotoAndPlay` method. If that sorts out your question, it would be great if you could mark it as answered too. Cheers!